# From HTML form to PDF

Tags: html, forms, pdf

Is there an easy way to have an HTML form on a webpage that, when the user submits, puts the data into a PDF file and sends it to the receiver?

The webpage is running on .net.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Umbraco](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/xsl-pdf-creator) has a good PDF generator package called "XSL to PDF".

It wil allow you to generate a PDF file from Umbraco just by defining a PDF template.

Using this you should be able to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you have C# use one of this libraries : 
http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries

(I don't use dot net, so I can't really recommend any, sorry)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [PDFsharp](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/) a lot.. Does the job!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ["PDF Vision .Net"](http://pdf-doc.com/convert-images-tiff-html-to-pdf/pdf-from-web-site-html-and-image-into-asp-net.php)? It's a commercial library but the costs of paying justify itself :) Only $150. I think you should try it.

Use this code for the HTML to PDF converting in Asp .NET/C#:

```
        SautinSoft.PdfVision obj  = new SautinSoft.PdfVision();
    obj.PageStyle.PageSize.A4();
    byte [] pdf = obj.ConvertHtmlFileToPDFStream(@"http://www.somesite.com");
    if (pdf!= null)
    {
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/PDF";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition:", "attachment; filename=Result.pdf");
        Response.BinaryWrite(pdf);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm working for this company.

I can also mention another great product of Sautinsoft company. I think you should check them both and then choose the best! The library quite well doing their job and doesn't require any additional components.

[PDF Metamorphosis .Net](http://pdf-doc.com/convert-html-to-pdf/component-rtf-html-text-to-pdf-csharp-aspnet.php)

This component

HTML to PDF in C#:

```
SautinSoft.PdfMetamorphosis p = new SautinSoft.PdfMetamorphosis();
p.PageStyle.PageSize.A4();
p.HtmlToPdfConvertFile(@"c:\table.html", @"c:\Result.pdf");
```

Comment: Please don't make it a habit of answering only posts that promote your company's products.  I appreciate that you disclose your affiliation, but please try to make contributions to the site that are more than just for your company's products.